# Issue with OptimisticLockType.DIRTY not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    runApplication<JpaTest>(*args).getBean(JpaTest::class.java).test()
}

@SpringBootApplication
class JpaTest
{
    @Autowired
    lateinit var repository: PersonRepository

    fun test()
    {
        repository.save(Person())

        runBlocking {

            suspend fun update(name: String, delay: Long)
            {
                val p = repository.findById(1).get()
                delay(delay)

                println("=== $name")
                p.name = name
                repository.save(p)
            }

            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                awaitAll(
                    async { update("Right Name", 3000) },
                    async { update("Wrong Name", 5000) }
                )

                println(" ")
                val p = repository.findById(1).get()
                println("Final: $p")
                println(" ")
            }
        }

        exitProcess(0)
    }
}

@Repository
interface PersonRepository : CrudRepository<Person, Long>

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@OptimisticLocking(type=OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
data class Person(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long = 0,

    var name: String = "?",
)
```

I'm trying to simulate a multi-threaded environment (or multiple instances of the same app running) **where an entity is fetch from the database at the same time**, changed and persisted.

When the first save task runs (3s later):

```
=== Right Name
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_0_0_, person0_.name as name2_0_0_ from person person0_ where person0_.id=?
2021-03-24 09:18:38.565 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2021-03-24 09:18:38.566 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([name2_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [UNKNOWN]
Hibernate: update person set name=? where id=? and name=?
2021-03-24 09:18:38.567 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Right Name]
2021-03-24 09:18:38.568 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2021-03-24 09:18:38.568 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [UNKNOWN]
```

When the second save task runs (5s later):

```
=== Wrong Name
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_0_0_, person0_.name as name2_0_0_ from person person0_ where person0_.id=?
2021-03-24 09:18:40.556 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2021-03-24 09:18:40.556 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([name2_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Right Name]
Hibernate: update person set name=? where id=? and name=?
2021-03-24 09:18:40.557 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Wrong Name]
2021-03-24 09:18:40.557 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2021-03-24 09:18:40.557 TRACE 21791 --- [atcher-worker-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Right Name]
```

Please note that both tasks fetched the database for the same object and then slept for 3s/5s before updating/saving.

The issue here is that the `second task` **fetched the database again** before updating, meaning that the `first task` changes are lost. I tried adding `@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)` but it also didn't work.

I was expecting that when `second task` attempted to persist the entity, an `OptimisticLockException` would be thrown.

If I change the lockType to `VERSION` it works as expected and `second task`'s update is rejected. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any transaction boundaries declared.
As a result of this every call to a repository runs in its own transaction.
And this is why the entity gets loaded (again) as part of the `save` operation.

If you wrap the load, wait, save cycle into a single transaction you'll see your desired behaviour.

In your test you can do that using a [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) for which the [usage is described in the Spring Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.5-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-prog-template).

Regarding the follow up questions:

> Any ideas of why `VERSION` works?

I don't have prove of the following, but this is what I strongly suspect.

With `DIRTY` the original state of all the columns is stored in the session, therefor it is the state of the load operation within the current transaction.

With `VERSION` the original state is part of the entity and therefore it survives across transaction boundaries.

> If I have to wrap everything since load into a transaction, wouldn’t that be a bad practice depending on what I’m doing between load and save?

While I agree that transactions should be as short as possible, they shouldn't be shorter than they need to be in order to do their job. I wouldn't expect transactions of a few seconds to be problematic as long as you don't have any blocking locks.

If you want to point at a bad practice, i.e. one that needs a good explanation why you use it, that would probably using `OptimisticLockType.DIRTY`. There is a reason why `OptimisticLockType.VERSION` is recommended and the default.

Comment: Any ideas of why VERSION works without a transaction tho? Also, if I have to wrap everything since load into a transaction, wouldn’t that be a bad practice depending on what I’m doing between load and save? Example: I might be performing an http request between save/load, which could hang the transaction for way too long.